# Having trouble with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I just need help in why this code does not work. I am unfamiliar with tkinter and this is the code that I was given and was told it should work. I see it says root is not defined but not sure what it should be defined as because I am assuming root is from tkinter? The only thing is that line 2 is grayed out. If you could help it would be greatly appreciated!

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import *


class MyFirstGUI:

    def __init__(self):
        root.gui = tk.TK()
        root.gui.title("A simple GUI")
        root.gui.label = tk.Label(text="This is our first GUI!")
        root.label.pack()
        root.greet_button = tk.Button(text="Greet", command=self.greet)
        root.greet_button.pack()
        root.close_button = tk.Button(text="Close", command=self.gui.destroy)
        root.close_button.pack()
    def greet(root):
        print("Greetings!")
root.mainloop()

my_gui = MyFirstGUI()
```

Comment: I don't know what `root` is or why you think it should already be defined.  I guess you think it must come from `tkinter`, but obviously, it does not.  What makes you think that `root` is defined?

Comment: See my answer.  I'm curious, so please let me know if it makes sense given what you were wanting to do.

Comment: Ok I am just confused as I do not know about tkinter. I do not know anything about it liked I mentioned. Also I do not think root is defined.  When I run it it says it is not. Just trying to make sense of what my proffesor sent us.

Comment: I can't know what your professor intended if they gave you exactly the code you are showing us.  There is definitely no reason to assume that `root` is already defined, and that exact variable name is often used to hold the app via `root = Tk()`. Could it be that there's other code he gave you that defines `root` in this way?

Comment: Pretty much he gave us this as an example to see the code. He mentions this "Try executing this code for yourself. You should be able to see a window with a title, a text label and two buttons – one which prints a message in the console, and one which closes the window. The window should have all the normal properties of any other window you encounter in your window manager – you are probably able to drag it around by the title bar, resize it by dragging the frame, and maximize, minimize or close it using buttons on the title bar." So basically we are suppose to use this to help us start.

Comment: The only thing was, was that when I went to try out the code it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah.  A mystery.  I guess you can ask him about it.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question.

Comment: Michael M please stop... I am new and trying to just understand this code. Literally all I asked is why this won't work. This is from a beginners perspective so sorry if it wasn't extremely detailed for you. I tried to ask it in a non-confusing way but I also am new to all this. Thank you CryptoFool for helping me even though I know it was a bit confusing. The code you sent works. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identifier `root` is often assigned from `tk.Tk()`.  If that's the case, then `root` will be the Tk application and the root of the Tk display graph.

You do all of your setup in the `MyFirstGUI` class's constructor, but you only use a local variable to keep track of the results.  You therefore lose access to all of it when you exit the constructor.
I expect that you want to create everything as a `root` attribute on `self` so that your setup is encapsulated and preserved by the class.

Here's how I would rework your code to get it to do what I think you intend:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class MyFirstGUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("A simple GUI")
        self.root.label = tk.Label(text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.root.label.pack()
        self.root.greet_button = tk.Button(text="Greet", command=self.greet)
        self.root.greet_button.pack()
        self.root.close_button = tk.Button(text="Close", command=self.root.destroy)
        self.root.close_button.pack()

    def greet(root):
        print("Greetings!")

my_gui = MyFirstGUI()
my_gui.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When this code is inputed I receive a name error mentioning that tk is not defined

Comment: Oops.  Sorry.  I didn't bring along the import statements.  I added them to my answer.  That exact block of code works for me, giving me two buttons in a window, one of which causes a print to the console, the other of which quits the app.

Comment: Ok thanks! No problem. I am still new to all this is general so I am just having more trouble. Thanks